# Recover MySQL database from .frm

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ubuntu

I had two different MySQL installations, one on Ubuntu and another on Windows 7. I wanted to migrate the database on Windows 7 (source) onto Ubuntu (destination).

Some Googling informed me that I have to copy the "datadir" contents to the other installation. This is where I committed a mistake. I did not back up my Ubuntu datadir. My second mistake was copying the entire datadir from source to destination MySQL including the "mysql" folder and files ibdata1, ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1.

With this my MySQL on Ubuntu crashed. I deleted the ib* files to get MySQL started. After MySQL started, I tried the "show databases" command. Then it listed all the databases from both the source and destination MySQL's. I am able to also list all the tables in the databases. However, when I try executing a "select" query, I get the following error:-

ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'itcc.testcase' doesn't exist

When I inspect the folders of my datadir, I see only the .frm files.

Can someone let me know how I can recover my DB and get it up and running?

Comment: Is database on windows machine available?

Comment: Yes, the database on windows machine is available and in tact. The one on Ubuntu is corrupted.

Comment: So why don't you copy the database from windows again?

Comment: The two databases contain different schemas. I want to move the one on Windows to Ubuntu without disturbing the existing schemas on Ubuntu.

Comment: You've deleted InnoDB files (ibdata) where InnoDB stores tables. You can recover database structure from frm files on Ubuntu(I prefer method described in http://www.slideshare.net/akuzminsky/data-recovery-talk-on-pluk, slide 42), but there are other tools around, one from oracle is good. Then you have to copy data from Windows to Ubuntu again. But not simple file copy, that won't work.

Comment: in case you need the deleted data on Ubuntu (if it's diverged since migration from Windows) then you need to scan the disk partition and fetch records from it (see https://twindb.com/recover-after-drop-table-innodb_file_per_table-on/ for details)

Comment: I haven't deleted but actually overridden the ib* files (the one on Ubuntu is overridden by the one from Windows). Basically I wanted to merge the schemas from Windows MySQL on Ubuntu MySQL and not migrate.